# Dynamic model filter in Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm looking for a way to make a dynamic & global model filter in Laravel.
I'm imagining a function like the following in my User.php model:

```
public function filter() {
    return ($someVariable === true);
}
```

Whenever I do a query using Eloquent's query builder, I only want users to show up in the collection when the filter above returns true. I would have thought a feature like that existed, but a quick look at the documentation suggests otherwise. Or did I miss it?

Comment: Show your function with return user collection

Comment: @IlyaYaremchuk I have many hundreds. They almost all use Eloquent's query builder though (so something along the lines of `User::with(...)->where(...)........->groupBy(...)->get()`). Also for `User::find(...)` I would like to return null when the filter doesn't pass. The raw queries I can do manually, it's about the query builder results. Thanks.

Comment: may be `if($someVariable === false){return null;}else{return User::find(...);}` :)

Comment: @IlyaYaremchuk I'm looking for a global solution, I have a project with many controllers and models. I don't want to shove if statements everywhere I access this model.

Comment: Where does `$someVariable` come from?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Anywhere. The idea being that the variable will be checked  during runtime (after receiving the results from the sql server, but before returning the collection). For context: my application has 2 modes. Based on the active mode, some users should / shouldn't be in the collection. So in this case $someVariable is a session variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. For now I've simply added a post filter option to the models using the following code:

```
// Apply a post filter on the model collection
$data = $data->filter(function($modelObject) {
    return (method_exists($modelObject, 'postFilter')) ? $modelObject->postFilter($modelObject) : true;
});
```

in `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php`'s get() function, after creating the collection. This allows me to add a function `postFilter($model)` into my model which returns either true or false.

Probably not the cleanest solution but a working one for now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is Query Scopes.

They are methods that may be defined in a global or local context, that mutate the current query for a given model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes

For example:

Lets say I have a database table called "Teams" and it has a column on it called "Wins." If I wanted to retrieve all Teams that had a number of Wins between Aand B I could write the following Local scope method on the teams model:

```
public function scopeWinsBetween($query, int $min, int $max)
{
    return $query->whereBetween('wins', $min, $max);
}
```

And it could be invoked as such:

```
$teams = Teams::winsBetween(50, 100)->get();
```

Comment: Hi @Endl, thanks. I came across this feature, but sadly this is only for query constraints. This doesn't allow me to check variables living inside my PHP scope. So in my example $someVariable isn't a column in my table, it's a local PHP variable.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question then. Have you considered wrapping all your Eloquent calls in another object, and having it filter the query results?

Comment: No worries, thanks for trying anyways :-) And that would be the last resort, but really I would like to implement this in my model, as it makes my code a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use Collection macro but you will need to suffix all your eloquent `get();` to `get()->userDynamicFilter();`

```
Collection::macro('userDynamicFilter', function () {
    //$expected = ...
    return $this->filter(function ($value) use($expected) {
        return $value == $expected;
    });
});
```

Comment: Ha, didn't know about macros yet, that's cool and certainly an option. Still looking for a method of doing this inside my model and without additional clutter in my code though. Let's see if anybody comes up with the true solution. Thanks!